# What changes do I, as an individual, experience during a recession?

Tags: microeconomics

There is a lot of talk about how we're approaching an economic recession. There is plenty of talk about how that would affect the world at large, but I haven't really found much on the level of private individuals (other than increased unemployment rates). When the economy fell during 2008 my family didn't really notice it as neither of my parents lost their job (granted, I was a high school freshman at the time so I can't really tell whether or not my parents had any issues).

So, my question is more or less: **As long as I don't lose my job, what changes to my life am I likely to see if we have another recession similar to the one in 2008?**